# Django social auth for facebook giving an error

Tags: django, django-models, django-socialauth, django-1.4

**I am using:**

- django-social-auth v 0.7.19
- django 1.4.3

**models.py:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 64, blank = True, null = True)
    last_login = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(blank = True)
```

**social_auth pipeline.py:**

```
from social_auth.backends.pipeline.user import create_user


def create_user(backend, details, response, uid, username, user=None, *args,
            **kwargs):

    if user:
        return {'user': user}
    if not username:
        return None

    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username = username)
    profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = user)

    return {
        'user': user,
        'profile' : profile,
        'is_new': True
    }
```

**Problem:**

1. When I take out the fields username, last_login and is_active from my model, the social auth would give me a DataBaseError as these columns are necessary. I am taking ForeignKey User but it cannot detect it.
2. I am overriding the create_user method of social auth to create my user and their profile. When the function returns, a user and profile is created but still it redirects on the error page. Cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your profile creation with this code:

```
profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user, defaults={
    'username': user.username,
    'last_login': date.today(),
    'is_active': True
})
```

Or add some default values to those fields.

Edit: keyword argument is defaults not default.